# Where can I find the definition of struct Qdisc?

Tags: linux, networking, operating-system

Googling gives [linux/qdisc.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/trace/events/qdisc.h) but I don't see the definition of `struct Qdisc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct QDisc
```

should be found when you include

```
#include <net/sch_generic.h>
```

(see https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/net/sch_generic.h)